# Как через одну форму создать «Категорию» и запись в этой категории?

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Делаю сайт на django по ведению и управлению заявок
Есть две модели:
"Заявка"

```
class Request(models.Model):
    id_request     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status         = models.CharField(default="Подписание" , max_length=20)
    nomer_request  = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    data_request   = models.DateField()
    person_request = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nomer_request)
```

и "Материалы заявки"

```
class Request_material(models.Model):
    id_request     = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status         = models.CharField(default="Подписание" , max_length=20)
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mnemokod_SAP   = models.IntegerField()
    ed_izm         = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    priznak_rem    = models.BooleanField()
    price          = models.IntegerField()
    colvo_request  = models.IntegerField()
    prihod         = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    spisan         = models.DateField (null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Вопрос связан с формой создания заявки. Как сохранить и связать эти данные.

То есть в результате я планирую получить форму, где в рамках одной формы можно будет создать заявку по модели Request и в этой же форме добавить материалы заявки по модели Request_material и их соединить связью один-ко-многим с самой заявкой...

Буду благодарна за разъяснения

Comment: Думаю объяснить по подробнее все же придется. Давай так, какой функционал на выходе ты ожидаешь получить?

Comment: Uncle_Ragnar, хорошо. Поправила сообщение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете отобразить обе формы:

```
class RequestForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ("status", "nomer_request", ...)


class RequestMaterialForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ("status", "name", ...)
```

html:

```
<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ request_form.as_p }}
    {{ requestmaterial_form.as_p }}
</form>
```

views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    requestform = RequestForm(request.POST)
    materialform = RequesMaterialtForm(request.POST)
    if requestform.is_valid() and materialform.is_valid():
        req = requestform.save()
        materialform.save(commit=False)
        materialform.id_request = req
        meterialform.save()
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, большое.